# Recursive Success handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, jspdf, html2canvas

am using html2canvas to convert 3 images to canvas then to PDF using jsPDF. My aim is to have each image in single page.

I need help in converting one image to canvas on success of previous image's conversion.

[Demo to Play](https://jsfiddle.net/3ddzqxwj/)

```
html2canvas(clone, {
onrendered: function(canvasObj) {
    //objs.push(canvasObj);
    console.log("1")
    startPrintProcess(1,canvasObj,pdf, pdfConf, 'printedPDF',function (){
    //alert('PDF saved');
    console.log("2")
     offScreen = document.getElementById('svg1');
        clone = hiddenClone(offScreen);
        html2canvas(clone, {
        onrendered: function(canvasObj) {
            //objs.push(canvasObj);
            console.log("1")
             startPrintProcess(2,canvasObj,pdf, pdfConf, 'printedPDF',function (){
            //alert('PDF saved');
            console.log("2")
                offScreen = document.getElementById('svg2');
                clone = hiddenClone(offScreen);
                html2canvas(clone, {
                    onrendered: function(canvasObj) {
                    //objs.push(canvasObj);
                      console.log("1")
                      startPrintProcess(3,canvasObj,pdf, pdfConf, 'printedPDF',function (){
                          //alert('PDF saved');
                      console.log("2")
                      pdf.save('fileName.pdf');
                      });
                      console.log("On Rendered!!");
                    }
                  });
            });
            console.log("On Rendered!!");
        }
      });
    });
    console.log("On Rendered!!");
}
```

});

Basically i want to make the above code dynamic and recursive.

Thanks in advance!